# How to add nodes in TreeView control from two different Forms in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, treeview

My program:

Form (Form1) contains:

- button1 control
- TreeView1 control

Form (Form2) contains:

- burron1 control
- label1 control
- label2 control

ClassArray

- public static **ar2** array

My aim is to make each element from **ar2** array as a node in the **TreeView1** control using both forms (**Form1** and **Form2**). The tricky thing is that I need only elements which meet specific conditions to be added from **Form2**. I don't know how to do that.

I added **if condition** pretending that next element is special and must be added from Form2.

```
                if (element == "3")
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2(counter);
                frm2.Show();
                break; 
            }
```

So when element is equal to 3 call Form2 and add the next element only from Form2.

On **Form2** I need to click button1 and add the **this special element only** (in this case element 4) and then the rest of the elements have to be automatically added from **foreach loop** in Form1.

Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int counter = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string element in ClassArray.ar2)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(element);
            counter++;

            if (element == "3")
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2(counter);
                frm2.Show();
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClassArray code:

```
    class ClassArray
{
    public static string[] ar2 = new string[8] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };

}
```

Form2 code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2(int counter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "Elements added from Form1 = "+counter.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add the special element as a note
    }
}
```

[image]

Click to add the special element as a node in TreeView1.

Then the **foreach** loop should continue until meet the next condition or if no condition it will continue to the end adding all the elements from **ar2** as nodes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to understand your problem. Can you try explain it more clearly?

Comment: I am adding nodes from Form1 up to element 3. Then I need to add next element from Form2 and then foreach loop to continue adding nodes automatically from where it is stopped.

Comment: frm2.Show(); break;  change it to frm2.ShowDialog(); continue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Form1 create public method, so that TreeView node could be added from outside.

```
    public void AddElement(int index)
    {
        string element = ClassArray.ar2[index];
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(element);
        counter++;
    }
```

Rework `button1_Click` code to use `AddElement` method. Also replace `foreach` loop with `for`. This way it will be possible to skip one element, that you will add from `Form2`.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ClassArray.ar2.Length; i++)
        {
            AddElement(i);

            if (ClassArray.ar2[i] == "3")
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2(counter);
                // ShowDialog will stop code execution until dialog is closed
                frm2.ShowDialog(this); // "this" - will be a Dialog Owner; it will come in handy in Form2
                i++; // skip "4"
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in `Form2` take a `Form1` instance and call previously created `AddElement` to add another node into TreeView.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add the rest of the elemnts as notes
        Form1 form = Owner as Form1;
        form.AddElement(currentElementIndex);
    }
```

`currentElementIndex` is just a class level variable, which holds a `counter` value.

```
    int currentElementIndex = 0;

    public Form2(int counter)
    {
        ...
        currentElementIndex = counter;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
ShowDialog() solved the problem.

Thank you :)